# I'm trying to plot a line of quantiles, but it' not appearing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm totally beginner at R and I’m with a problem to plot a line of quantiles. The line of "mean" appear, but the "quantiles" not.

Someone can help me? :)

My code:

```
ggplot(data = pf, aes(x = age, y = friend_count)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 1/20, position = position_jitter(h = 0), color = ‘orange’) +
  xlim(13, 90) +
  coord_trans(y = ‘sqrt’) +
  geom_line(stat = ‘summary’, fun.y = ‘mean’) +
  geom_line(stat = ‘summary’, fun.y = ‘quantile’, fun.args = list(probs = 0.1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to show deciles (10th percentile, 20th, etc.) and you want to show them as straight regression lines you could add `geom_quantile(quantiles = seq(.1, .9, by = .1))` at the end instead of `geom_line(stat = ‘summary’, fun.y = ‘quantile’, fun.args = list(probs = 0.1))`

For example:

```
ggplot(data = cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist)) +
    geom_point() +  geom_quantile(quantiles = seq(.1, .9, by = .1))
```

Gives:
[image]